# How to unwind dates from date range in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongodb model defined in mongoose for nodejs like:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  serial: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  date_from: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  date_to: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }});
```

I have a functionality that shall return the number of days free for a given period and serial. So, given the date range from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-15, I would to query the db and get as a result something like:

```
const busy_days = [
"2020-01-01 00:00:00", 
"2020-01-02 00:00:00", 
"2020-01-03 00:00:00", 
"2020-01-08 00:00:00"
"2020-01-09 00:00:00",
"2020-01-10 00:00:00",
"2020-01-14 00:00:00",
"2020-01-15 00:00:00"
]
```

After, my idea is to complete the rest of the algorithm with NodeJs, by checking which dates between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-15 are not in the busy_days list.

Is there the possibility to do that kind of query in mongoDb?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of searching, I found some examples and the solution may be:

```
schema.statics.foo = function () {

  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        days_diff: {
          $divide: [{
            $subtract: ["$date_to", "$date_from"]
          }, 86400000.0]
        }
      }
    }, {
      $project: {
        dates_in_between_inclusive: {
          $map: {
            input: { $range: [0, { $add: ["$days_diff", 1] }] }, // +1 for inclusive
            as: "dd",
            in: { $add: ["$date_from", { $multiply: ["$$dd", 86400000] }] }
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      $unwind: "$dates_in_between_inclusive"
    }, {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        dates: {
          $addToSet: "$dates_in_between_inclusive"
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
};
```

I have to evaluate still if this is the most efficient solution and if it scales.

Comment: Making `$unwind` and afterwards an `$group` looks a bit pointless. Just remove them.